# Django linux server image storing

Tags: python, django

I am developing an application with an image gallery using Django. By the way, shop products also have photos. At the moment, website is been deployed on the linux server. Here is the question: should i upload images to the linux server using *ImageField* or it is better practise to use separate cloud storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use centralised cloud storage (S3, Azure, Google Cloud) in case your application is deployed across several such linux servers or if your server goes down and is replaced by another one.

See DjangoStorages and its S3 integration: https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html

It has integrations for other cloud providers as well.